# Querying Instances table android calendar API

Tags: android, calendar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to query the Instances table in the Android calendar API. However, the exception I am getting says "Invalid column sync_data1".

Since I am accessing the table as a sync adapter, the uri below is what I use.

```
Uri instanceUri = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI
.buildUpon()
.appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
.build()
```

I then add the start and end times to the uri using the two lines below...

```
instanceUri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(instanceUri, start);
instanceUri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(instanceUri, end);
```

And the I run the query like this...

```
Cursor cursor=cr.query(instanceUri,PROJECTION,selection,selectionArgs,Instances.BEGIN);
```

In the PROJECTION, some of the columns I wish to retrieve are "Instances.SYNC_DATA1, Instances.SYNC_DATA2 and Instances.SYNC_DATA3". These are only accessible as a sync adapter but this is what I have done so I have no idea what could be going wrong.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen that CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER is only for inserting, updating and deleting.
But then how is the CalendarContract.Instances.SYNC_DATA1 column accessed?